# Case function in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of format

```
    id name flag
  ----------------
    11 Jack  1
    11 Jill  2
    23 Joe   1
    23 John  2
    23 Sam   1
    46 White 2
    46 Dan   2
    57 Dave  1
```

I am trying to return the table of format (based on the flag for particular id) like

```
    id name_1 name_2
   ------------------
    11 Jack   Jill
    23 Joe    John
    23 Sam    John
    46 NULL   White
    46 NULL   Dan
    57 Dave   NULL
```

I tried this query but it does not give the expected result.

```
select id,
case flag when 1 then name end as name_1,
case flag when 2 then name end as name_2
from temp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a join, not a select case.  Something like this, assuming null is possible in either column:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name fname, b.name lname from
(SELECT id, name FROM temp WHERE flag = 1) a 
full outer join 
(SELECT id, name FROM temp WHERE flag = 2) b on a.id = b.id
```

Not sure what you expect in this case though:

```
46 NULL   White
46 NULL   Dan
```

Comment: I think that's meant to be a `FULL OUTER JOIN` rather than a `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: well as you specified your query returns the first 3 rows and not the rows which has null's in name_1 or name_2. But I want the partial result too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to use case for this.  This should do the trick, however:

```
select t1.id, t1.name as name_1, t2.name as name_2
from temp t1
    inner join temp t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.flag = 1 and t2.flag = 2
```

I'm not sure you can get your partial result from the same query, so you could always do a union to find these...

```
select t1.id, t1.name as name_1, t2.name as name_2
from temp t1
    inner join temp t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.flag = 1 and t2.flag = 2

union

select t1.id, t1.name as name_1, t2.name as name_2
from temp t1
    left join temp t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.flag = 1 and t2.flag = 2
where t2.id is null

union

select t2.id, t1.name as name_1, t2.name as name_2
from temp t2
    left join temp t1 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.flag = 1 and t2.flag = 2
where t1.id is null
```

This will get totally screwed up if there are 3 rows with the same ID :)

Comment: your query does not return the rows which has NULL in name_1 or name_2

Comment: Added another option to bring in the partial results with unions.